# Regular Expression Extractor Jmeter

Tags: javascript, regex, jmeter

Hi All I am trying to extract the token from the below mentioned JSON Response (only Token value no prefix or suffix is required).

The regular ex what is used is:  `"token":"(.*?)"`

but below is the returned value after using the reg ex.

```
"token":"eyJpZCI6IjgzNjg4IiwiZXhwIjoxNDYzMDQ2NDg3LCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsImV4dGVybmFsaWQiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsInJvbGVzIjpbIkhJRFN5c0FkbWluIl0sImF1ZCI6InN5c1JNMyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC91c2Jvc3MtdHN0NHRyZXNzOjQ0M1wvYWMuNHRyZXNzLnNhbWxpZHBcL1NJU0RPTUFJTlwvYXV0aG4iLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTQ2Mjk2MDA4NywiZ3JvdXBpZHMiOlsiMTAwMCJdfQasddds12"
```

**But I don't want `"token":"` and the last `"` to be returned.**

Please help me in writing the regular expression that meets my criteria.

**Actual JSON Response**

```
{  
   "statusCode":200,
   "result":{  
      "list":[  
         {  
            "provider":"openID",
            "token":"eyJpZCI6IjgzNjg4IiwiZXhwIjoxNDYzMDQ2NDg3LCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsImV4dGVybmFsaWQiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsInJvbGVzIjpbIkhJRFN5c0FkbWluIl0sImF1ZCI6InN5c1JNMyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC91c2Jvc3MtdHN0NHRyZXNzOjQ0M1wvYWMuNHRyZXNzLnNhbWxpZHBcL1NJU0RPTUFJTlwvYXV0aG4iLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTQ2Mjk2MDA4NywiZ3JvdXBpZHMiOlsiMTAwMCJdfQasddds12",
            "username":"authNauthor2@adasd.com",
            "audience":"sysRM3",
            "expires":1463046487,
            "roles":[  
               "asdasd"
            ],
            "groups":[  
               "1000"
            ]
         },
         {  
            "EMAIL":"authNauthor2@asdasd.com",
            "ENDPOINT_ID":null,
            "KEY_AUTHORIZATIONS":"IqweQWQCE-001, asdasd-002",
            "EU_COMPANY_NAME":"asdasdasd"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: What problem has occurred? It works perfectly fine with me ([live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH8cL7/2)).

Answer (score 1):

Looking into RegExp Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image: View Results Tree]

Your regular expression is valid, so you just need to use `$1$` as Template in the Regular Expression Extractor. Full configuration:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
- Regular Expression: `"token":"(.*?)"`
- Template: `$1$`

Refer extracted value as `${token}` where required.

You can check extracted variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler):

[image: Debug Sampler]

---

It might be easier to use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) in order to deal with JSON data, it is extremely convenient when it comes to conditional selection like "extract token where email is authNauthor2@asdasd.com"

Relevant JSON Path Expression will be as simple as `$..token[0]`.

See:

- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for overview and syntax reference
- [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) for some scenarios covered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the difference between a `match` and a `capturing group`. Let's lighten your data a bit and just consider:

```
"token":"eyJpZCI6IjgzN"
```

Your pattern : `"token":"(.*)"` will *match* the whole line while the *capturing group* will capture the content inside the parenthesis (here, the token value : `eyJpZCI6IjgzN`).

Your need to get the value of the capturing group:

```js
    var re = /"token":"(.*)"/; 
    var str = '{  \n   "statusCode":200,\n   "result":{  \n      "list":[  \n         {  \n            "provider":"openID",\n            "token":"eyJpZCI6IjgzNjg4IiwiZXhwIjoxNDYzMDQ2NDg3LCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsImV4dGVybmFsaWQiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsInJvbGVzIjpbIkhJRFN5c0FkbWluIl0sImF1ZCI6InN5c1JNMyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC91c2Jvc3MtdHN0NHRyZXNzOjQ0M1wvYWMuNHRyZXNzLnNhbWxpZHBcL1NJU0RPTUFJTlwvYXV0aG4iLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhdXRoTmF1dGhvcjJAaGlkZ2xvYmFsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTQ2Mjk2MDA4NywiZ3JvdXBpZHMiOlsiMTAwMCJdfQasddds12",\n            "username":"authNauthor2@adasd.com",\n            "audience":"sysRM3",\n            "expires":1463046487,\n            "roles":[  \n               "asdasd"\n            ],\n            "groups":[  \n               "1000"\n            ]\n         },\n         {  \n            "EMAIL":"authNauthor2@asdasd.com",\n            "ENDPOINT_ID":null,\n            "KEY_AUTHORIZATIONS":"IqweQWQCE-001, asdasd-002",\n            "EU_COMPANY_NAME":"asdasdasd"\n         }\n      ]\n   }\n}';
    var m;
     
    if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
      
        document.body.innerHTML += m[1];
       
    }
```

Here, `m[0]` holds the match while `m[1]` hold the capturing group value